# How to loop through a SimpleXMLElement object rest client in Php?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, codeigniter, simplexml

How to loop through a SimpleXMLElement object? This is what I have: I tried in many ways to iterate, but no success:

```
 Array
 (
    [status] => 1
    [data_nilai_siswa] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [id_siswa] => 1
                        [nama_siswa] => 1
                        [n_bahasa] => 1.00
                        [n_matematika] => 1.00
                        [n_binggris] => 1.00
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [id_siswa] => 2
                        [nama_siswa] => 2
                        [n_bahasa] => 2.00
                        [n_matematika] => 2.00
                        [n_binggris] => 2.00
                    )
            )
       )
 )
```

i use library rest client [philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814) and script rest client:

```
$xmlResponse = $this->rest->get('http://127.0.0.1/EJ/testclient2/getdata/nilai');
$projects = array();

foreach($xmlResponse->project as $project) {
 $projects[$project->id_siswa] = $project->nama_siswa;
 echo 'Project ' . $project->nama_siswa . ' has ID ' . $project->id_siswa . PHP_EOL;
}
```

i get the error Message: Trying to get property of non-object? how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point it directly to the `item` property.

```
foreach($xmlResponse->data_nilai_siswa->item as $project) {
    $projects[$project->id_siswa] = $project->nama_siswa;
    echo 'Project ' . $project->nama_siswa . ' has ID ' . $project->id_siswa . '<br/>'; 
}
```

Comment: thanks..this working but I found Message: Illegal offset type.

Comment: $projects[$project->->item->id_siswa] = $project->->item->nama_siswa; i add this.and work. thanks for help..